# Checking for key name in nested json

Tags: c#, json, linq, lambda

I need to check if a keyname exists in a json file, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Json file:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "from": 1430611201000,
      "to": 1430697600000,
      "ref": "2015-05-03",
      "value": "8.4",
      "quality": "Y"
    }
  ],
  "updated": 1430726400000,
  "parameter": {
    "key": "2",
    "name": "Lufttemperatur",
    "summary": "medelvärde 1 dygn, 1 gång/dygn, kl 00",
    "unit": "degree celsius"
  },
```

I think this is the closest I got, but it will always be false (even when I search for an existing key):
content is a JObject.

```
var searchDate = content.Properties().Select(p => p.Value).Children().Any(p=>p.Contains("quality"));
```

EDIT: I've changed the key name to "quality", for clarifing the question. 
I will also use another json file that contains the key "date" instead of "from" and "to". To seperate the files I want to know is "date" exists or not.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Assuming this was correctly written, you still have no property named "_date_", so it's not strange that you would get a _false_ value. Bad example perhaps? Explain your expected output. Or should this find "up**date**d"?

Comment: Bad example.. when I'm trying I'm searching for an existing key, change "date" to "quality" then I want it to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the property to be checked is always belong to an item in the `value` property, then you can do this way :

```
var isQualityExists = 
            content["value"].Any(v => ((JObject)v).Properties()
                                                  .Any(p => p.Name.Contains("quality"))
                                );
```

Otherwise, you may want to create a function that recursively check for a specific property name existence all over the `JObject`.

Comment: That's beautiful! It's working!
Someone with reputation, please vote this answer up.

Comment: @user3741174 If it's working, and you're happy, then accept it as _answer_.

Answer (score 0):

date does not exist in json. Thats why you get false as mentioned in one of the comments.
If you want to search for key:"to"

```
if("to" in json_object) 
{
//your logic goes here
}
```